# (Recursively?) Fill a table with a variable number of rows, depending on a value in another column in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a concept of [newspaper, magazine] editions where each region can specify how frequently they want to publish them.  One region might publish it every month, another might have it only once per year.

```
select id, frequency from regions;
 id | frequency
----+-----------
  1 | 1 year
  2 | 6 mons
  3 | 4 mons
  4 | 1 mon
```

The name of the edition is a date to make it easier to translate it, since it is always the name of the month (in the language it was written in) and the year it was published.  The start/end dates are reference points for which articles should be considered for inclusion in the edition (there's another table containing a link between article/edition, since not all articles get published).

```
select region_id, name, date_start, date_end from editions;
 region_id |    name    |       date_start       |        date_end
-----------+------------+------------------------+------------------------
         1 | 2013-01-01 | 2012-03-24 00:00:00-04 | 2012-12-23 23:59:59-05
         2 | 2013-01-01 | 2012-09-24 00:00:00-04 | 2012-12-23 23:59:59-05
         3 | 2013-01-01 | 2012-11-24 00:00:00-05 | 2012-12-23 23:59:59-05
         4 | 2013-01-01 | 2013-02-24 00:00:00-05 | 2012-12-23 23:59:59-05
         2 | 2013-07-01 | 2012-12-24 00:00:00-05 | 2013-12-23 23:59:59-05
         1 | 2014-01-01 | 2012-12-24 00:00:00-05 | 2014-12-23 23:59:59-05
         4 | 2013-02-01 | 2012-12-24 00:00:00-05 | 2013-02-23 23:59:59-05
         3 | 2013-05-01 | 2012-12-24 00:00:00-05 | 2013-08-23 23:59:59-04
```

I have this query for generating the *next* edition for each region:

```
INSERT INTO editions
    (region_id, name, date_start, date_end)
SELECT 
    regions.id,
    (last_edition.name + regions.frequency) :: date AS name,
    last_edition.date_end + interval '1 second' AS date_start,
    last_edition.name + regions.frequency + regions.frequency - interval '1 month' + interval '22 23:59:59' AS date_end
FROM
    (SELECT region_id, max(name) :: timestamp AS name, max(date_end) AS date_end FROM editions GROUP BY region_id, date_end) AS last_edition JOIN
    regions ON regions.id = last_edition.region_id
```

The problem with it is that it will make an equal number of editions for each region every time I run the query.  What I'm looking for is a query where if I specify a date, it will generate all of the editions starting from the most recent edition for every single region up until that date.  For instance, if the date is a year from now, it would generate the following number of editions:

- 1 edition per region with a frequency of `1 year`
- 2 editions per region with a frequency of `6 months`
- 4 editions per region with a frequency of `3 months`
- 12 editions per region with a frequency of `1 month`

This sort of query would typically be run via cron job for all of the regions at once, but could be run for a specific region if their editions need to be regenerated because they've changed their frequency.

Comment: Why do you group by `date_end` in your sub select? `GROUP BY region_id, date_end` ?

Comment: Your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Have you tried something like `generate_series( Max(date_end), date_specified, frequency)`?

Comment: I was initially selecting the `date_end` without the max and forgot to remove it from the `group by`.  I am using 9.1 at the moment, but will be upgrading to 9.2.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that function, so it will take me some time to figure out how to use it.

Comment: I already wrote an answer using this function. You can use it as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
    regions.id,
    name as last_name, 
    generate_series(name + frequency,'2015-01-01',frequency) as name,

    generate_series(name + frequency,'2015-01-01',frequency) 
    + frequency 
    - interval '1 month' 
    + interval '23 days' AS date_start,

    generate_series(name + frequency,'2015-01-01',frequency) 
    + 2 * frequency 
    - interval '1 month' 
    + interval '22 23:59:59' AS date_end

FROM (SELECT region_id, max(name) AS name
      FROM editions 
      GROUP BY region_id) AS last_edition 
JOIN regions ON regions.id = last_edition.region_id

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

to generate all editions from the most recent to the date specified (`'2015-01-01'` in example).

Comment: @cimmanon You can ask me, if you don't understand something. Or use official PostgreSQL manual (like [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) particular page).